When I use langchain's RAG method to search local txt, some content cannot be searched
When I use langchain's RAG method to search local txt, some content cannot be searched. Every time I change chunk_size, the content that cannot be searched will be different.The content in the file is Chinese. The TextLoader can successfully load all the content.
from langchain import hub
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
import re

loader = TextLoader("knowledge.txt")
data = loader.load()


with open("geometry-knowledges-chinese.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    content = file.read()
lines = content.split('\n')
titles = []
for line in lines:
    match = re.search(r'"([^"]+)"', line)
    if match:
        titles.append(match.group(1))



model_name = "BAAI/bge-small-en"
model_kwargs = {"device": "cpu"}
encode_kwargs = {"normalize_embeddings": True}
hf=HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(model_name=model_name, model_kwargs=model_kwargs, encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs)

# Split
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    separators=[
        "\n\n",
        "\n",
        "\uff0e",  # Fullwidth full stop
        "\u3002",  # Ideographic full stop
    ],
    chunk_size =300, chunk_overlap = 50,length_function = len,add_start_index = True)
all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

# Store splits
vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(documents=all_splits, embedding=hf)

# RAG prompt
template = """Use the following context to search for answers to your questions.
    If you don't know the answer, just say you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
    Don't add anything else.{context}
    Question: {question}
    Helpful Answer:"""
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["context", "question"],
    template=template,
)

# LLM
llm = Ollama(model="llama3.1")

# RetrievalQA
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm,
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    chain_type_kwargs={"prompt":QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
)
for title in titles:
    specific_question = f"Definition of{title}"
    result = qa_chain({"query": specific_question})
    print(f"Definition of{title}:{result['result']}")


How should I modify the code to allow the LLM to search for all the content?

Your code looks correct. I would advice three things to debug.

Your chunking strategy may not be suitable for your dataset. Try play around with chunk size and overlap values to arrive at optimal retrieval.
I can see you have two txt file. Ensure you have actual data in vector for your query.
Try this below for now, and let me know what happens.


qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(
        search_type="mmr",
        search_kwargs={'k': 6, 'lambda_mult': 0.25}
        ),
        chain_type_kwargs={"prompt":QA_CHAIN_PROMPT}
)


Thank you for your response.
Regarding the first point, I have tried multiple chunk sizes, but there are always some entries that the LLM does not know.
For the second point, I am searching for the content of the first file, while the content of the second file is only used to extract the titles of the entries, such as 'triangle,' which makes it easier for me to ask questions of the LLM. I have already confirmed that the titles extracted from this file are correct.

As for the third point, after using this code, if the LLM does not know the answer, it no longer responds with 'I don't know,' but instead chooses the content of another entry as the answer, which is often incorrect.

Is it possible to share the two sample txt file?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eQ1DVPBo91X7eKZ8xiXAenxmuyqGpz_p?usp=drive_link
Sure, you can download it from the link above.

Dont have access, requested

Sorry, now you can download it.
